# Cakephp 3 update value in validation provider if returning false

Tags: validation, cakephp

In my model I would like to update a value in my validation provider

For exemple if the $value = '4012*'
It is not alphanumeric so I want $value to empty to save it my database

Model/Table/ProductsTable

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator 
        ->allowEmpty('code')
        ->add('code', 'alphaNum', [
              'rule' => 'isalphaNum',
              'message' => 'Code is wrong',
              'provider' => 'table']);
    return $validator;
}

public function isalphaNum($value, array $context)
{
  if (!ctype_alnum($value)) {
    //Update a warning table
    $warning = new Warnings;
    $warning->insert('Code is wrong',
                     $context['data']['code'],
                     $context['field'],
                     $value
                   );
   //UPDATE THE VALUE TO EMPTY
   $value = "";

  } 
    return true;
}
```

The problem is when I debug my value in my isalphaNum function, it is empty, Good!. But after the validation and when it is saved in the database it is my intial value saved in this exemple '4012*'.

Where should I change my value?

Comment: This looks like something you should perhaps do in the [beforeMarshal callback](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities) instead of validation.

Comment: Thank you Greg for your reply. As you said I will use the before Marshal callback